# AlertDialog.Builder.setView vs AlertDialog.setView

Tags: android, alert

Is there any difference between these methods? I'd like to create the dialog first so that I have the reference to it when something is clicked in the view to dismiss it. Obviously that's not possible if I'm setting the view with the builder and the alert is not created yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [AlertDialog.Builder source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/AlertDialog.java#AlertDialog.Builder.setView%28android.view.View%29) it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

> "I'd like to create the dialog first so that I have the reference to
>   it when something is clicked in the view to dismiss it."

The user can't click to dismiss the dialog until to you show it to them, and that is after you have created an instance.  See the lifecycle example below:

```
    View someView = ...;
    View someOtherView= ...;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    //sets the view, but doesn't show anything.     
    builder.setView(someView);  

    //now we have an instance of AlertDialog, still not shown
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    //now we showed it
    dialog.show();

    //...(wait some time)
    //now we changed its view after being shown
    dialog.setView(someOtherView);
```

Comment: I wasn't very clear. My question was asking if there are any benefits/disadvantages to using setView in the builder vs. the alert itself.

Comment: They set the same variables.  The builder sets the variables on an internal dialog its building, the other one sets it on an existing one.  The distinction is when you use them.